# Android OnDraw()

Tags: android

I am new to Android and I am having trouble understanding the concept so basically this is what i want to do to understand it better..

- I created a DrawShape class that extends view. In this class in the OnDraw() I am creating a circle and filling it with a color.
- From the Activity I am calling the application. //Until this point I am doing fine.

Now, I need to re-paint the Circle multiple times (Blue, Red, Yellow etc..)

So I was reading and the best way is to use Threads.. I also read you need to use postInvalidate() to redraw (I still dont understand from where I should be calling this) is this called from the Activity?, or within the OnDraw()?.

Hopefully you understand what i want to accomplish, is just that i havent found a good tutorial that shows this, how to repaint something x amount of times .. when I do Thread.sleep() it all stops then it shows my app.. but now i understand why, because i am playing with the main Thread.

Please help me understand this..

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

i did something like this

```
animcolor()
{
Timer timer = new Timer();
int delay =  ...;
int period = ...;
timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
   run() { 
         setColor( randomint() ); ) 
         customview.postInvalidate();
   }
}, delay, period);
```

threads? not necessary to create them; Timers make a good job on concurrency.

... and the code would somewhat look like....

`res/layout/file.xml`

```
<org.customviewlayout a:id="@+id/customlayout"/>



src/org.MyActivity.java


class MyActivity 
{
  onCreate()
  {
    customlayout = findViewById(R.id.customlayout);
    customlayout.animcolor();
   }
}
```

`src/org.customlayout.java`

```
import org.customview;
class customlayout
{
  customview;

  customlayout(context, attrs)
  {
    customview = new customview();
    addview(customview);  // so it's onDraw() method will be called
  }

  onlayout(...)
  {
    customview.layout(...);
  }

  animcolor()
  {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    int delay =  ...;
    int period = ...;
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
       run() { 
           setColor( randomint() ); ) 
           customview.postInvalidate();
       }
    }, delay, period);

  }

  setcolor(int)
  {
    ....
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think, you can do this using a Timer and a TimerTask inside your activity. The TimerTask runs with the delay you specify and when run all you what to do is yourDrawShapeInstance.postInvalidate();

the mechanism is this, because you arent on the ui thread you call postInvalidate() to add an invalidate on the ui queue, when the ui engine pick the delayed invalidate that you invoke before, then calls automatically the onDraw method of your DrawShape view and the view will be redrawed.

(i don´t test this, i write here)

```
TimerTask task = new TimerTask(){
  public void run(){
    myDrawShapeInstance.postInvalidate();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When drawing, always use a thread away from the main thread and always invalidate after thread has finished (for the most part -- to display current results from drawing). You will probably call your drawing functions from some user-related event, so make sure you're making another thread for that drawing process. Follow those rules and you will be fine.

```
void drawCircleToCanvas(int color)
{
final Handler handler = new Handler() {
           public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
              myDrawShapeInstance.postInvalidate();
              }
           };
        Thread updateUI = new Thread() {  
           public void run() {

           //************draw something here***************

              handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
              }
           };
          updateUI.start();
}
```

Comment: Great, if I need to redraw the circle then in the run() i can put something like Canvas c = new Canvas(); and Paint paint = new Paint(); Can i do this from here? what would you suggest? and Also, what If I have a class that Extends View, can I do something like myClass.OnDraw(); ?

Comment: A couple things here: The thread should be used to update values that affect the canvas. Such as moving the position of a character in a game ++x (move character horizontally over a position). You can use the thread to change the value of the number of circles to draw and the colors to change them to. By calling postInvalidate(), the canvas onDraw() function will be called too, so you don't need to call onDraw() directly. This link has code very similar to what you are doing: http://blog.goltergaul.de/2010/03/android-game-project-basics-of-threads-and-canvas/